# How i can convert ISO time format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to convert data format from `2019-08-03 01:08:58.155000` to  `2019-08-03 01:08:58` using python

I am trying to avoid all chars after `.`

**Code:**

```
mod_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(max_startdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**Error:**

> "unconverted data remains .155000"

Comment: I want datetime object.., Thanks

Comment: mod_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(max_startdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: If that's your attempt so far, you should [edit] your question to include that code, and explain where exactly you are stuck. See also [help.](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')              
'03-08-2019 12:43:16'
```

If you `max_startdate` is string,

```
>>> max_startdate = '2019-08-03 01:08:58.155000'
>>> max_startdate.split('.')[0]     
'2019-08-03 01:08:58'
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's giving "unconverted data remains .155000" error.   mod_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(max_startdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: @Rahul how you define `max_startdate` in your code? Add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks ,I have used split func .